# why is my unordered_map getting bigger and bigger

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I used unordered_map, the key is string, the value is a class IpsegInfo.
I read a file and used the file data to update the value in map, the map size always same but the map space in memory is getting bigger and bigger.

My code update the map from file every 30 minutes, the file has 10million lines and the length never changed, only the data would be change. So my map length is always same as 10 million as well. The file physical size is 500MB, the unordered_map memory size is 4GB after first time load, but after a few hours the map size become 50GB and it's getting bigger continually, I think I should have somewhere did memory leak.

My code as following:

```
class IpsegInfo {
    public:
        string country;
        string province;
        string isp;
        string asn;
        IpsegInfo();
        IpsegInfo(string country, string province, string isp, string asn);
        ~IpsegInfo();
};
//one thread is doing the map refresh. other threads read the map for quick access.
unordered_map<string, IpsegInfo> IpsegMap::map;
void refresh(){
  while(1){
   string line;
   string delim = ",";
   ifstream ipsegFile("/opt/test/ipseg.txt");
   if(ipsegFile.is_open()){
     while (getline(ipsegFile,line) ){
        trim(line);
        vector<string> ss = comUtil.split(line,delim);
        IpsegInfo *info = new IpsegInfo(ss[1],ss[2],ss[3],ss[4]);
        map[ss[0]] = *info;
     }
   }
   ipsegFile.close();
   sleep(60*30);
   }
}
```

Comment: Where does this memory get freed: `IpsegInfo *info = new ...`

Comment: Change the variable name for your `unordered_map` to something other than `map`. Don't use typenames as variable names.

Comment: @Jarvis `map` is not a keyword and in fact is a perfectly legal and legitimate variable name for a C++ program.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 I didn't, should I do delete before insert to map:  delete map[ss[0]];

Comment: But `map[ss[0]]` is an object of type `IpsegInfo`. It's not a pointer. It's not something that you have allocated. In the `refresh` function **`info`** is a pointer to something you have allocated, but you never `delete` it. The solution is not not use `new` or the temporary `info` variable at all, just assign directly to `map[ss[0]]`.

Comment: @Jack What you need to do is figure out which data structure owns the memory you allocated, and from there, when to free it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the issue is not with the unnecessary local variable `info`, it's with the allocated memory, which is never freed.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but that `if(ipsegFile.is_open())` isn’t needed. The call to `getline` will fail if the file isn’t open.

Comment: @Jarvis — one of the reasons we have namespaces is so that you don’t have to dodge around names that are defined in various libraries. There’s no reason to avoid the name `map`. If you get a conflict with `std::map` its because you did something silly like `using namespace std;`, which blows away the separation that namespaces give you.

Comment: A couple of other best practices, unrelated to solving your problem. You probably shouldn't declare the default constructor and destructor for this class. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three (rule of 0 applies more than 3/5 here). You also probably want to do `map[ss[0]] = IpsegInfo(ss[1], ss[2], ss[3], ss[4])` because it's more efficient than the version with `info` being created then copied.

Comment: @Charlie Thank you so much, I was a Java programmer, so need to change :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        IpsegInfo *info = new IpsegInfo(ss[1],ss[2],ss[3],ss[4]);
        map[ss[0]] = *info;
```

Here you create a `IpsegInfo` using new. That means that you should also delete it using `delete`.
Instead you simply override it, creating a memory leak. Use RAII to make your data automatically managed:

```
        IpsegInfo info = IpsegInfo(ss[1],ss[2],ss[3],ss[4]); // no pointers!
        map[ss[0]] = info;
```

Comment: The `info` variable isn't even needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes. I left it there so the changes would be easier to see. Also: `using namespace std` considered bad practise!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just tried, it works, thanks a lot! why it was not overwritten when using new IpsegInfo(), but it was overwritten without new? btw, should I use map.erase() before insert?

Comment: @Jack — when you create an object with `new` you are taking responsibility for destroying it when you’re finished with it. You **must** delete it at some point if you don’t want a memory leak. You **could** eliminate the leak with `delete info;` after the assignment to `map[ss[0]]`, but the solution in this answer is a better approach. Let the compiler handle the bookkeeping to destroy the object.